# Merge makes my computation very slow as compared to create in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I ran two query in my desktop application, on same dataset(containing 20000 rows).

first:-

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row
CREATE (n:MyNode{name:row.source})
```

second:-

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row
MERGE (n:MyNode{name:row.source})
```

Here CREATE is taking just 140 milli sec. while MERGE is taking about 90 second
which is about 600 time slower.

I have about 60 million rows and I need to create distinct node. Is there any suggestion, that I can use to decrease the execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MERGE is like a MATCH (followed by a CREATE if nothing was matched), it benefits from an index, and will suffer if an index doesn't exist on the properties involved (similar to unindexed MATCHes).

Please create an index (or unique constraint, if it is applicable) on :MyNode(name), then retry your load.

Comment: first I ran this code..
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:domain) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE

after this executed:
profile LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row
merge (n:domain{name:row.domain_id})

this worked, I am new to neo4j, could you explain in little detail, how is this working. Thanks

Comment: Please review our documentation on [using indexes for search performance](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/).